# React.js server side rendering with Java [without Node.js]

Tags: java, node.js, tomcat, reactjs

We have an application in pure JSP/JQuery which we are trying to move to ReactJs for maintainability. One of the benefits of ReactJs I am seeing is server side rendering. However, all the examples I have seen of server side rendering utilize Node.js as a server side. We are currently using Tomcat and not so much inclined to deploy node.js just for server side rendering.

I have considered few alternatives such as using Nashorn (http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/)

However, Nashorn doesn't seem to be production ready.

Has anyone deployed React.js with server side rendering on Tomcat on production?

Comment: Nashrom has been relased with Java 8 so I expect Oracle consider it to be production ready. See http://augustl.com/blog/2014/jdk8_react_rendering_on_server/ for rendering React app server side with Java.

Comment: Why would you think running react on the server is more maintainable than JSP?

Comment: Why do you want to render it in server with React and not with JSP?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Trying to render a Javascript app serverside without NodeJS is an excellent way to torture yourself. Trying to run javascript inside a jvm is even worse. I would recommend against it.

It is possible to render the complete client server side using PhantomJS (which technically runs without Node) or even using xvfb and Chrome on *nix. All have been done, with various degrees of painful debugging.

Running the javascript *inside* tomcat itself is rather unusual… I can't see the point other than "because we can". My best guess is that nobody is doing that in production.

Comment: I agree for the most part, however .NET has a server-side rendering framework for reactjs. So I don't think you necessarily need to run javascript in JVM to accomplish this. JSX is essentially JS+XML, so you could probably pre-render the template without too much pain. I don't think it's required to accomplish some level of server-side rendering by interpreting JS server side.

Comment: Just because nobody has publicly documented rendering React components from Java does not mean it's hard or a torture. Really, running JavaScript in Java is not hard, complicated or unusual. This has been part of the the standard JRE since well before JavaScript became popular on the server side. We used embeded JavaScript in a Java application on production years ago (at the time, we used the old Rhino engine).

Comment: @PierreBuyle I'm using a hyperbole in my answer (maybe I should edit that out), but my experience with Rhino wasn't very positive when I tried to use it  to simulate a browser app. Maybe you're smarter or more lucky than me, but you might agree that it's not the path of least resistance.

Comment: Running a browser app in a non browser runtime is indeed painful to do. Usually, server side React is not done by running the full browser app. But rather by rendering the appropriate React component after loading the required data using server side code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a step further with server-side rendering and make real-time single-page web applications in reactive style without Node.js in plain Java language?

The [Reactive Server Pages](https://github.com/vadimv/rsp) project uses the approach similar to the Elixir Phoenix Live View or Scala Korolev frameworks.

Motivation:

- Responsive web UI in familiar Java, no client-server APIs, no JS
  frameworks and npm dependencies management needed;
- Lightweight SSR generated almost plain HTML page to be SEO friendly;
- UI components are regular Java classes;
- Brings application rendering workload and UI logic from a client's browser to the
  server, your code always stays on your server;
- Debug UI code as any normal Java code;
- Built with Java web standards, currently runs on Jetty, but in
  theory, should work on Tomcat as well.